# Programming Contests (with prizes)

Tags: netflix

I've had a go at solving the [Eternity puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternity_puzzle) (1,000,000 GBP prize) and [Netflix Prize](http://www.netflixprize.com/) ($1,000,000) in the past. I didn't win either, but they motivated me to find out about a new area.

What other contests with prizes do you know about / have competed in yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.topcoder.com/

Answer (score 3):

The [Millenium Problems](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/).

Answer (score 2):

There is an eternity 2 project, although it has been out for a bit and the first solutions are being checked on Dec 31.

http://www.eternityii.com/

Answer (score 1):

[The Netflix Prize](http://www.netflixprize.com/) (for voting)

Answer (score 0):

I entered the STM32-Primer [2009 programming contest](http://www.stm32circle.com/projects/list.php?contest_2009=1), came in 5th place with my [Solitaire program](http://www.stm32circle.com/projects/project.php?id=74).

[alt text http://www.stm32circle.com/projects/contestAnnouncement.gif](http://www.stm32circle.com/projects/contestAnnouncement.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I have started a website with much smaller scale programming contests called  [Code Competition](http://codecompetition.com) that are run each month.